# sending mail from my domain in php

Tags: php, email, smtp, smtp-auth

I'm trying to send a mail from my own domain server like xyz@mydomain.com in php.

I can successfully send mail using gmail account with pear package. But, sending messages from my own domain fails.

any idea..... how I should send messages from my own domain. I'm getting errors like

```
authentication failure [SMTP: SMTP server does not support authentication (
    code: 250, response: EMU.dnsracks.com Hello [72.18.135.214] TURN SIZE 2097152 
    ETRN PIPELINING DSN ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 8bitmime BINARYMIME CHUNKING VRFY OK)]
```

My mail address is xyz@mydomain.com

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to authenticate into a SMTP server that does not accept authentication. You should try to fix that first.

Comment: that i know... so what should i do to fix my problem...

Comment: You have to fix that problem *on smtp server*, not in PHP

Comment: You can try to *not* authenticate. I mean, you don't send a username and password by default, you have to write code to do so.

Comment: whoohoo open relay smtp server open for all spammers! what server is it windos or linus?if it is hosted somewhere by a company then it most probalby does not need a password- just send email- it uses DNS to verify where it is comming from.. if it is like a dedicated server then you need to close it up tight.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use smtp, just use the phpmailer class.
http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html

very easy to use and you'll be sending emails in minutes!